# Constant voltage LED driver to constant current conversion

Tags: led, led-driver, constant-current, constant-voltage

I have 12 pieces of wrong supplied Meanwell LPV-35-24 LED drivers which are of constant voltage type onboard a vessel. Our lighting fixtures are using constant current drivers and I run out of spares. There is any way to modify those drivers to be used in constant current mode?

Comment: Not really. You could maybe make them work with a resistor, but it'd waste some power. We'd need a lot more detail either way.

Comment: Please explain why you cannot return the incorrectly supplied units.

Comment: It's very complicated to return items from the ship, sometimes the shipping is more expensive than item itself and the supply is very slow, sometimes we order the spares and need to wait up to 6 months until they arrive onboard.

Comment: Do you have resistors available that you could solder in to turn your constant current lights into constant voltage? I wouldn't recommend it but sounds like you are stuck.